# What is the role of Winston Wolfe?

Tags: pulp-fiction

In the movie [*Pulp Fiction*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/) Winston Wolfe says about himself: *"I'm Winston Wolfe. I solve problems."*. But what does he mean with that and what really was his role?

Comment: Be sure to ask an actual question in the question body, apart from a mere quote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wolfe is what is known as a cleaner - someone who cleans up crime scenes for the mob. He is a fixer and facilitator - he knows how to dispose of bodies and how to create alibis.

For more information, check out the ['cleaner' page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaner_%28crime%29).